# Request for non-class type member

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to implement a BST, but I keep getting stuck with the following error on compile:

```
bstavl.cpp: In member function ‘bool BSTree::find(int)’:
bstavl.cpp:114:15: error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘((BSTree*)this)->BSTree::root->BSTNode::left’, which is of non-class type ‘BSTNode*’
bstavl.cpp:120:16: error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘((BSTree*)this)->BSTree::root->BSTNode::right’, which is of non-class type ‘BSTNode*’
```

I'm implementing a struct of BSTNode and the class BSTree is using a BSTNode pointer as the root. Here's the declaration of the classes and struct:

```
struct BSTNode {
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//instance variables 
int value; 
bool deleted;
struct BSTNode *left;
struct BSTNode *right;
int height;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//constructors

//non argumented constructor
BSTNode() {
    this->value     = 0;
    this->height    = 0;
    this->left      = NULL;
    this->right     = NULL;
    this->deleted   = false;
}

//given value
BSTNode(int value) {
    this->value     = value;
    this->height    = 0;
    this->left      = NULL;
    this->right     = NULL;
    this->deleted   = false;
}

//given value, left pointer, right pointer
BSTNode(int value, BSTNode *left, BSTNode *right) {
    this->value     = value;
    this->height    = 0;
    this->left      = left;
    this->right     = right;
    this->deleted   = false;
}
};

//=====================================================================

class BSTree : public BSTNode {
BSTNode *root;

public: 
BSTree();
BSTree(int);
bool isEmpty(); //check if the bst is empty
void insert(int newValue); //inserts an int into the bst. Returns success
bool find(int value); //searches bst for int. True if int is in tree
void preorder(); //calls recursive transversal
void inorder(); //calls recursive traversal
void postorder(); //calls recursive transversal
int height(BSTNode *n);
int totalheight(); //returns tot height. height of empty tree = -1
int totaldepth(); //returns tot depth. depth of empty tree = -1
int avgheight(); //returns avg height of tree
int avgdepth(); //returns avg depth of tree
bool remove(int value); //deletes int. returns true if deleted

private:
struct BSTNode* insertRecursive(struct BSTNode *n, int newValue);
void inorderRecursive(BSTNode *n); //traverses tree in inorder
void preorderRecursive(BSTNode *n); //traverses tree in preorder
void postorderRecursive(BSTNode *n); //traverses tree in preorder

};
```

Finally, here is the implementation for BSTree::find

```
bool BSTree::find(int findMe){
if (root->value == findMe)
    return true;
else if (findMe < root->value){
    if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left.find(findMe);
    else
        return false;
}//else if
else if (findMe > root->value){
    if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right.find(findMe);
    else 
        return false;
}//else if
}//find
```

Any advice you have to offer would be great. I've tried changing the line

```
root->right.find(findMe);
```

to all sorts of things including

```
(root->right).find(findMe); 
root->right->find(findMe);
(root->right)->find(findMe);
```

and plenty others but with errors on compile. I know it's probably a simple fix somewhere but I've spent hours on this one stupid simple function with no progress and it's really starting to frustrate me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It basically comes down to the fact that `BSTNode` doesn't have a `find` method.

And your `find` method currently uses `root`, which is not defined in `BSTNode`.

I suggest you move away from having a tree inherit off a node. Since a tree is not a node (it simply contains one), this inheritance isn't particularly good.

Rather create another class `BSTGeneric` which all your tree implementations will inherit off of (methods like `find` will be here, since it will look the same for all BST's, other methods can be declared here as [pure virtual](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/)).

Then, for each current recursive function, add another one that takes in a `BSTNode *` parameter, which should be private, and let the current function simply call that.

So, instead of:

```
public: void insert(int value)
{
  ...
  root->left->insert(value);
  ...
}
```

We'll have:

```
public: void insert(int value)
{
  insert(root, value);
}

private: void insert(BSTNode n, int value)
{
  ...
  insert(n.left, value);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why would I add a BSTNode parameter? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of defining the function in a class? I have another class following, AVLTree that I plan on implementing, and I need to call the function with the same name two different ways. That's why I was defining it as a class method to begin with. Since AVLTree would also use BSTNode, that wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: Are all the nodes in your `BSTree` tree `BSTree` objects, or are they `BSTNode` objects?

Comment: hmm... good thought. They're BSTNodes. Also, casting the variable to BSTree compiles fine but causes a segfault when passing a tree to it

Comment: @dawkinsjh Edited - Largely rewrote my answer.